# Need help in Swift imageview controller to another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

```
  @IBAction func savePicture(sender: AnyObject) {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(mainImageView.frame.size,false,0.0)
        mainImageView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        let alert = SCLAlertView()

        alert.addButton("YES", action: {
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,nil,nil,nil)
            //Save pop success tips
            let alert1 = SCLAlertView()
            alert1.showSuccess(self, title: "Saved successfully", subTitle: "^_^", closeButtonTitle: "OK", duration: 0)

            //I want to link to another View controller
        })

        alert.showInfo(self, title: "Okay to save？", subTitle: "Pictures will be saved to the album", closeButtonTitle: "NO", duration: 0)
       }
```

I need to link to another ***TableViewController*** after they have successfully save the picture in the photo library.

**I have tried push with this code but it does not work

```
 var VC1 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyViewController") as ViewController
            let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC1) // Creating a navigation controller with VC1 at the root of the navigation stack.
            self.presentViewController(navController, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

Please help me thanks!!

Comment: Can't you just perform a segue?

Comment: do u want to pass the image to next view controller?

Comment: We need more information. What did not work? What have you seen? Are there any errors printed to the console?

Comment: I can't seem to perform segue it gives me a blank screen, and when I start the TableViewController as the initial View Controller it works normally. So I need help to link them after I have save

Comment: @dasdom please advise

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is broken. `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` can also fail hence the `completionTarget` and `completionSelector` exist. You should check them.

Because you do use Storyboards, the easiest way is to create segue in Storyboard with some name. Let's say `show-image`. Then you just call `performSegueWithIdentifier("show-image", sender: image)` and that's it. Where `image` is some reference to the image you would like to pass (if you would like to do it). If you do not want to pass image, just pass `nil` there.

Then override `prepareForSegue`, check if `segue.identifier` equals to `show-image` and then assign your `image` reference (`sender` in this case) to some `segue.destinationViewController` property.

But it's hard to help or be more specific, because you don't provide more details about what's wrong.

Comment: It's a mess :-) But your `MemeEditor` storyboard ID is set  in `UINavigationController` in Storyboard, not the `AddTableViewController` you want.